# Android custom file name to a pdf document in Lollipop is not working

Tags: android, pdf

I was using following piece of code in **Kitkat** to generate pdf file. Some how it used to generate the pdf file name as per my  given text.

but in **lollipop** the same piece of code is not functional.Its generating file name with **"RepoDocument.pdf"** where **Repo** is my application name

```
@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
        PrintAttributes newAttributes,
        CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
        LayoutResultCallback callback,
        Bundle metadata) 
   {
        // Create a new PdfDocument with the requested page attributes
        mPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(m_context, newAttributes);

        // Respond to cancellation request
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) 
       {
         callback.onLayoutCancelled();
         return;
       }

      // Compute the expected number of printed pages
      int pages =  computePageCount(newAttributes);

      if (pages > 0) 
      {
         // Return print information to print framework
         PrintDocumentInfo info = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("mycustomname.pdf")
         .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
         .setPageCount(pages).build();
         // Content layout reflow is complete
         callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
       }  
      else 
      {
        // Otherwise report an error to the print framework
        callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count calculation failed.");
      }
  }
```

What is the reason for this issue? let me know if you need some more input

Comment: You generate a pdf file you say. But is it a file? I see no code where you save it to the file system. And where do you see RepoDocument.pdf? And onLayout() is of which class?

Comment: PrintDocumentInfo class automatically saves this  file "RepoDocument.pdf" in default folder i.e My Documents . Its Automatically assign the                   "Application name + Document" tag to generate the file name. This is seen only in lollipop

Comment: Then i wonder which names would be given if you created two pdf documents.

Answer (score 0):

File name can be defined here

```
private void doPrint() {
// Get a PrintManager instance
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

// Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
String jobName = "DocumentName.pdf";

// Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
// to handle the generation of a print document
printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(getActivity()),
        null); //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the jobname is not meant to be the file name as it is only used to name the printing job.